# Bash scripts that writes a json array to a json file

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that generates uuids and writes that to a file, in a json array format.
I have written a simple code that generates the id and writes to a file but the issues i am running into are;

here is my own implementation

```
function uud {
     for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++));
     do 
         echo "\`uuidgen\`", >> $file
     done 
 }

 for file in file1.json file2.json;
 do 
     $( uud $1)
done
```

1. I am having issues with converting the ids into strings.
2. Converting the results to arrays.

Currently my solution prints the ids into the file in this format

```json
caca8fef-42d6-4b21-9d6b-0e40d348bd53,
e6e12fb5-4304-4ba9-b895-931bb4b58fbf,
df699ecd-d887-413e-8383-2a98ac2fa22f,
```

and this is what i want to acheive, How can I go about getting this result?

```json
[
"caca8fef-42d6-4b21-9d6b-0e40d348bd53",
"e6e12fb5-4304-4ba9-b895-931bb4b58fbf",
"df699ecd-d887-413e-8383-2a98ac2fa22f"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jq` to generate the JSON.

```
uud () {
    for ((i=0; i< $1; i++)); do
        uuidgen
    done
}

for file in file1.json file2.json; do
    uud 5 | jq -Rs 'rtrimstr("\n") | split("\n")' > "$file"
done
```

`-Rs` reads the entire input into a single JSON string, which you then split (after removing the trailing newline) on newlines to produce the desired array.

---

[One blogger](https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/reading-raw-text-into-jq/) suggests using two `jq` processes, which is more expensive but arguably simpler:

```
for file in file1.json file2.json; do
   uud | jq -R . | jq -s . > "$file"
done
```

Comment: End up with a trailing empty string in your list from the `split()` treating the terminating newline from the last entry as a split point. Maybe add a `[:-1]`?

Comment: Thanks; I've opted to strip the trailing newline before splitting.

Comment: (An alternative that I found while researching would be to use `jq` twice: `jq -R . | jq -s .`. I think a single process is still preferable, but the simplicity of the two separate commands is compelling.)

Comment: Single `jq` process, but not sure it is much easier to read: `jq --null-input '$ARGS.positional' --args $(uud 5) > "$file"`

Comment: Hm, `ARGS.positional` is newer, so I didn't think of that. I'm not crazy about the unquoted command substitution, but it *should* be safe assuming a standard value for `IFS`.

Answer (score 1):

I have adjusted slightly your script, try it:

```bash
function uud {
    echo "[" > $file
    for ((i=1;i<$1;i++));
    do 
        echo \"$(uuidgen)\", >> $file
    done 
    echo \"$(uuidgen)\" >> $file           # last item in array without comma 
    echo "]" >> $file
 }

for file in file1.json file2.json;
do 
    $( uud $1)
done
```

Or execute it [here](http://tpcg.io/_4KNXH2) and check the result.

Comment: `$(uud $1)`, not `uud "$1"` on its own? Why would you want to tell the shell to read the uud function's stdout and run that stdout as a separate command?

Comment: For that matter, is there a good reason for making uud depend on a global `file` variable instead of having it write to stdout? Taking all the `>$file` and `>>$file` out of the function and just invoking it with `uud >"$file"` would be a lot more clear.

Comment: ...the other thing is that the unquoted expansions you're doing are arguably safe with `uuidgen` but would be unsafe with other programs (things able to contain whitespace-surrounded wildcards in their output, f/e). Consider trying to make your code run [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/)-clean to reduce the likelihood of folks adapting it to different use cases tripping over bugs.

Comment: My intention here was adjust his own solution as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

After you've run your existing loop...

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > ed1 <<EOF
%s/^/"/g
%s/$/"/g
$s/,//
1i
[
.
$a
]
.
wq
EOF

ed -s file < ed1
```